# How do I optimize memory usage in PHP for this function?

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

This function is passed about 70k objects to process. It has no problem loading the array, and it gets through about half the iterations before it fails. Memory is limited to `ini_set('memory_limit','465M');` (cloud service). It always fails in the `$googleFunction`: `/app/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/src/Google/Api/Ads/Common/Lib/AdsSoapClient.php`.

I've already tried passing the array as a reference, switching from `array_chunk` to using an `array_slice` at a time, passing the `$chunk` by reference to the `$googleFunction`, unsetting the `$chunk` at the end, and calling `gc_collect_cycles()` after each iteration.

How can it still fail? There must be a memory leak somewhere, but there are no large assignments aside from `$chunk` and `$result`, and each function called goes out of scope during each iteration, so anything it may have allocated is supposed to be garbage collected. I feel it may have something to do with the function references. After about a quarter of the iterations, it uses 240M. It grows by about 10M per iteration.

```
  function googleJob($job = null, &$list, $googleFunction, $before = null) {
    // initialize $total, $gaw, $processed
    for ($chunkIndex = 0; $chunkIndex < count($list); $chunkIndex += 2000) { 
      echo '3:'.memory_get_usage().' ';
      $chunk = array_slice($list, $chunkIndex, 2000); # limit of 2000/request
      echo '4:'.memory_get_usage().' ';
      if ($before) {
        foreach ($chunk as $item) {
          $before($item); # function reference 
        }
      }
      echo '5:'.memory_get_usage().' ';

      $i = 0; // try harder to make Google work
      $result = null;
      do {
        try {
          $result = $gaw->$googleFunction($chunk);
          echo '6:'.memory_get_usage().' ';
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) { # try to remove the bad items and try again
          // no errors generated
        }
      } while ($result == null && $chunk); // Retry the request if not empty

      array_walk($chunk, function($item) { $item->save(); });
      echo '7:'.memory_get_usage().' ';
      $processed += count($chunk);
      if ($job) {
        $job->progress = round($processed / $total * 100);
        $job->save() or Yii::error($job->getErrors());
      }
      echo '8:'.memory_get_usage().' ';      
      unset($chunk);
      unset($result);
      echo '9:'.memory_get_usage().'... ';
      gc_collect_cycles();
      echo memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
```

Memory 'profiling' output:

```
3:110267832 4:110372112 5:111920328 6:123908368 7:129432080 8:129432080 9:121662520... 121662520
3:121662520 4:121766800 5:123281704 6:138001000 7:143493888 8:143493888 9:135745264... 135745264
```

Comment: May or may not be relevant here, but [this blog](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/what-about-garbage.html) describes in detail what garbage collection does. I've never had luck trying to tell PHP how to manage memory. It's not really designed that way.

Comment: you might want to consider using a queue to process these jobs

Comment: There's no point in passing `$list` as a reference, because you never modify that array.

Comment: What does `$item->save()` do? That looks like the only part of the function that will use lots of memory, because it saves every input item somewhere.

Comment: Also, does `$gaw->$googleFunction` save `$chunk` anywhere?

Comment: @Machavity I didn't see anything important in the blog. @FuzzyTree I do use a queue, but they cannot be processed because of memory problems. @Barmar I attempted to use a reference for `$list` so it wouldn't copy the whole 70k objects and it might save some memory. `$item->save()` saves to the DB. It works OK for about 35k times. `$googleFunction` does not save `$chunk`. It merely loops through it to make a web request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are abusing soap service. if you telling us that your code fails at $googleFunction I can offer you set the $chunk with 100 or 200 objects.

The second thing is a $item->save() function. If you have an access to the class you should check if there are  HAS-IS classes. The only place PHP leak the memory is like this construction:

```
class Foo {
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = new Bar($this);
    }
}

class Bar {
    function __construct($foo = null)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}



for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

     $foo = new Foo();
     unset($foo);
     echo number_format(memory_get_usage()) . "<br>";

}
```

so If you have objects, I suspect Active Record objects,  created in a save() function don't forget to unset them.
the easy way is to add destruct like this:

```
function __destruct()
    {
        unset($this->bar);
    }
```

This should help

Comment: [Google recommends 2000](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/limits#general), and supports up to 5000. But I will try 100 at a time, and test for leaks with circular references. Ok even with smaller chunks of 200, it still leaks.

Comment: Interesting, `$save()` does in fact leak memory! `foreach($agk as $v) {
      $v->save();
      echo memory_get_usage().PHP_EOL;
    }`